# Safari CSS transition on scale with border radius

Tags: css, safari

I came across a strange issue on Safari. Please take a look at: https://codepen.io/enguerranws/pen/PomzqWe

If you go hover the lightly red box, you'll notice a transition on an element inside.

If you test it in Chrome or Firefox, the animation runs as expected: **it's a small black circle that scales up.**

**On Safari, it goes weird: it's a black square with some kind of transparency that goes round and fully opaque when the transition ends.**

Here's the relevant part of code:

```
#test:hover #circle {
  transform: scale(200);
}
#circle {
  position: absolute;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
  /* transition: all 1s ease; */
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Does anyone as quick and dirty hack for this?

EDIT:

Actually, I found a way to get around this issue using `width` and `height` values for `transform`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `will-change: transform;`. Added to your code:

```css
#test {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 40% 10px;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.1);
}
#test:hover #circle {
  transform: scale(1);
}
#circle {
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
  will-change: transform;
  transform: scale(.005); /* point */
  transform-origin:left top;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 30px;
  border-radius: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="circle"></div>
  Text here  
</div>
```

Comment: I was having an issue where bottom border radius was reverting on transform, adding will-change was the solution